# change the size and orientation of legend title while plotting raster

Tags: r, raster, terra

```
library(terra)
library(RColorBrewer)

# sample polygon
p <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
p <- terra::vect(p)

# sample raster
r <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- terra::rast(r)
r <- terra::crop(r, p , snap = "out", mask = T)

terra::plot(r,
           col = brewer.pal(9, "pastel1"),
           cex.main = 2,
           smooth = T,
           legend = T,
           plg = list(title = "Score"),
           axes = TRUE,
           mar=c(3,3,3,6))
plot(p, add = T)
```

How do I change the size and orientation of the legend title 'Score'.
I want to orient the title so that it is vertical and follows along the
legend and also change the size of the legend title?

Comment: You can control legend title size with `plg = list(title = "Score", title.cex = 1.5)` for example, not sure how to change legend title angle and position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add text whereever you want. For example

```
library(terra)
p <- terra::vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- terra::rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))

plot(r, mar=c(3,3,3,6))
text(x=6.77, y=49.95, "Score", srt=-90, cex=2, xpd=NA, pos=4)
lines(p)
```

[image]